# add form inputs to table

Tags: javascript, session-storage

i'm stuck at the moment. i want to upload my inputs from my add tasks form to my tables new row which we create by pressing the button add task. now we get NEWCELL1 as a answer but i want my form inputs of course. i thought about doing this with session storage but the fact is i dont know how to use that in this scenario.
you're a hero if you can give me the solution and a legend if you can teach me how to find such problems myself ;)

```js
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
    cell4.innerHTML = "NEW CELL4";
    cell5.innerHTML = "NEW CELL5";
      cell5.innerHTML =   '<button class="button-add" type="button" onClick="deleteRow()" >'
      +  'delete</button>';
    }
```

```html
 <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>titel</th>
                <th>beschrijving</th>
                <th>deadline</th>
                <th>delete task</th>
              </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td><a href="detail.html">javascript</a></td>
                 <td>visuele aspecten</td>
                 <td>14-04-2020</td>
                 <td><input type="submit" value="delete"  onclick="deleteRow()"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>2</td>
                 <td><a href="detail.html">html</a></td>
                 <td>layout maken</td>
                 <td>14-04-2020</td>
                 <td class="button-1"><input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow()"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td><a href="detail.html">css</a></td>
                 <td>styling</td>
                 <td>14-04-2020</td>
                 <td class="button-1"><input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow()"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>4</td>
                   <td><a href="detail.html">php</a></td>
                   <td>backend werkend krijgen</td>
                   <td>14-04-2020</td>
                   <td class="button-1"><input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow()"></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>  
 
 
 <form >
            <h2>Add Tasks</h2> 
            titel: <input type="text" name="titel"><br />
            beschrijving: <input type="text" name="beschrijving"><br />
            deadline: <input type="date" name="deadline"><br />
            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Add" name="type" class="center" onclick="myFunction()"> -->
            <button type="button" value="Add" id="handler" class="center button-add" onclick="addRow();">Try it</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Normally, forms can only send input/select fields back to the server where you're wanting to save that data from the (input/select) fields, if the fields were part of the form when the page was loaded, unless you use AJAX and formdata, in which case you can send as much data and pretty much anything other than a file.  Therefore, you'd need to put the table in the form, but it wouldn't send the new rows when the form was submitted.  Look up AJAX and formdata to see how you can 'pack' multiple fields into a object and then send it to the server, and how to 'unpack' the data on the server.

Comment: ahh you're a saviour. pretty new to javascript and coding in general. i'm definitely gonna take a look at AJAX and formdata. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use document.querSelector to fetch the data from the inputs like document.querySelector('[name="titel"]').value;

```js
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = document.querySelector('[name="titel"]').value;
    cell3.innerHTML = document.querySelector('[name="beschrijving"]').value;
    cell4.innerHTML = document.querySelector('[name="deadline"]').value;
    cell5.innerHTML = "NEW CELL5";
      cell5.innerHTML =   '<button class="button-add" type="button" onClick="deleteRow()" >'
      +  'delete</button>';
    }
```

```html
 <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>titel</th>
                <th>beschrijving</th>
                <th>deadline</th>
                <th>delete task</th>
              </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td><a href="detail.html">javascript</a></td>
                 <td>visuele aspecten</td>
                 <td>14-04-2020</td>
                 <td><input type="submit" value="delete"  onclick="deleteRow()"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>2</td>
                 <td><a href="detail.html">html</a></td>
                 <td>layout maken</td>
                 <td>14-04-2020</td>
                 <td class="button-1"><input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow()"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td><a href="detail.html">css</a></td>
                 <td>styling</td>
                 <td>14-04-2020</td>
                 <td class="button-1"><input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow()"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>4</td>
                   <td><a href="detail.html">php</a></td>
                   <td>backend werkend krijgen</td>
                   <td>14-04-2020</td>
                   <td class="button-1"><input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow()"></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>  
 
 
 <form >
            <h2>Add Tasks</h2> 
            titel: <input type="text" name="titel"><br />
            beschrijving: <input type="text" name="beschrijving"><br />
            deadline: <input type="date" name="deadline"><br />
            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Add" name="type" class="center" onclick="myFunction()"> -->
            <button type="button" value="Add" id="handler" class="center button-add" onclick="addRow();">Try it</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Please understand the document.queryselector{all} functions are really just more flexible ways, as compared to the document.getelement{s}by... functions, to access the DOM elements in your web-page from javascript.  The queryselector{all}... functions just let you to use CSS selector to identify/search for the element(s) in addition to using the element's id, name, or tag type.  However, as you may already know, full-on jQuery selectors, also based on CSS, can go even farther with more complex searches, when needed.  However, this is all on the client-side.

Comment: But, this doesn't actually save your form's data to a server-side database or anything else, such as a file.  Incidentally, yes, you could save your data to session storage, but then the data would only be available on that one computer, a specific browser type (Chrome vs Edge or FireFox) and logged-in (OS-Wise) user account, and it would be less secure than saving it on a server and protecting it with a username and password scheme, if that's important to you.  Note, there are some non-standard ways to save data to regular files on your computer using APIs, but these have their limitations.

Comment: it's not going to go live, i just started coding and for this project i only needed a way to  send my inputs from the form to the table, but i regret the way i did it now, because they keep adding tasks in wich it was smarter to have started with a other approach.